# Eclipse slowing down OS

Tags: eclipse, performance, response

I have two laptops with similar parameters i7, 8Gb RAM. I installed Win7 and Eclipse Oxygen on both machines and for the better machine Eclipse is slowing down the whole OS. Eclipse takes its time, even when typing something, still shows (Not Responding) and freezes constantly. It affects other software as well and browser almost can't read the websites. I tried to turn off the automatic updates and uncheck some of the plug-ins but nothing has helped so far. I don't know what might be an issue here when on the other machine which has a little bit lower performance works smoothly.

Comment: Check that you don't have any stale threads running in the background, by clicking into the debug view and looking under the 'debug' pane. If you have set a breakpoint, it can be easy to end up with a handful of 'zombie' threads running that aren't obvious from the main view.

Comment: This is not really a development-related question.  Anyway, ever opened task manager and check what is consuming CPU/Memory or having lots of IO?

Comment: That is probably caused by a plug-in that you have installed. Start with a plain Eclipse Photon (Oxygen is outdated) installation and install your additional plug-ins one by one to find out which plug-in is slowing down the system.

Comment: I installed the Java Photon (sorry for a mistake) and this is a fresh install, so no plug-ins installed by me. I was not debugging anything. I checked out the processes in task manager and seems that Java is consuming most of the memory.